# Tampermonkey button get dom on button click

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Created a test script to test on google.com and don't have the info I want to get from the DOM yet. But I can't get the button to show testing on google.com (not the site I'll be using this on).

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name         Get DOM Info
    // @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
    // @version      0.1
    // @description  Button at top of page to retrieve information from the DOM and copy to clipboard
    // @author       name
    // @match        http://www.google.com
    // @grant        none
    // ==/UserScript==

    (function() {
        'use strict';

        // Function to retrieve information from the DOM
        function getInfoFromDOM() {
            // Get the title of the current webpage
            var pageTitle = document.title;
            return 'Page Title: ' + pageTitle;
        }

        // Function to create and append the button to the top of the page
        function addDOMInfoButton() {
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.innerHTML = 'Copy DOM Info';
            button.style.position = 'fixed';
            button.style.top = '10px';
            button.style.left = '10px';
            button.style.zIndex = '9999';
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                // Get information from the DOM
                var domInfo = getInfoFromDOM();

                // Create a temporary textarea to copy the text to the clipboard
                var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
                textarea.value = domInfo;
                document.body.appendChild(textarea);

                // Copy text to clipboard
                textarea.select();
                document.execCommand('copy');

                // Remove the temporary textarea
                document.body.removeChild(textarea);

                // Notify the user
                alert('DOM Info copied to clipboard:\n' + domInfo);
            });

            document.body.appendChild(button);
        }

        // Add the button when the DOM is ready
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addDOMInfoButton);
    })();
```

Tried changing location of button and just having the button show only.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, in @match put the address with https

```
@match https://www.google.es/
```

And comment the addEventListener function and calling it directly to the function you created and it appears. I put it in gray to see it better.

```
// ==UserScript==
    // @name         Get DOM Info
    // @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
    // @version      0.1
    // @description  Button at top of page to retrieve information from the DOM and copy to clipboard
    // @author       name
    // @match        https://www.google.es/
    // @grant        none
    // ==/UserScript==

    (function() {
        'use strict';

        // Function to retrieve information from the DOM
        function getInfoFromDOM() {
            // Get the title of the current webpage
            var pageTitle = document.title;
            return 'Page Title: ' + pageTitle;
        }

        // Function to create and append the button to the top of the page
        function addDOMInfoButton() {
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.innerHTML = 'Copy DOM Info';
            button.style.position = 'fixed';
            button.style.top = '10px';
            button.style.left = '10px';
            button.style.zIndex = '9999';
            button.style.background = 'gray';
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                // Get information from the DOM
                var domInfo = getInfoFromDOM();

                // Create a temporary textarea to copy the text to the clipboard
                var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
                textarea.value = domInfo;
                document.body.appendChild(textarea);

                // Copy text to clipboard
                textarea.select();
                document.execCommand('copy');

                // Remove the temporary textarea
                document.body.removeChild(textarea);

                // Notify the user
                alert('DOM Info copied to clipboard:\n' + domInfo);
            });

            document.body.appendChild(button);
        }

        // Add the button when the DOM is ready
        //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addDOMInfoButton);
        addDOMInfoButton();
    })();
```

Comment: Please, if it helped you, don't forget to mark the answer as good.